# Codename One Capture Audio Permissions on iOS

Tags: ios, codenameone

We are trying to capture voice notes on one of our app using the Capture.captureAudio() method.
On iOS, the recording starts before the permission prompt comes up resulting in a stuffed audio file.

Is there a way to prompt for the permission before the recording starts or are we doing something wrong.

Comment: I looked at the code and couldn't see something immediately wrong but there's a newer API of [AudioRecorderComponent](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/AudioRecorderComponent.html) which might be better. Unfortunately I can't find a sample for it